# What does it mean when a controlled system is supposed to react twice as fast?

Tags: control-system

For school we got the task to design a PI controller for a 2nd order plant. The system is supposed to react twice as fast as without controller. What is meant by "react twice as fast"? Because for a plant of second order, can you even measure how fast it reacts?

Comment: I'd think of "reaction time" as the time it takes to the system to reach a certain percentage margin of the setpoint

Comment: The assignment probably means either half the rise time, or half the settling time. I'd go with half the settling time personally, because the rise time option could be met by a wildly unstable controller. Or try to do both!

Comment: "react twice as fast" implies that the closed loop system does what is demanded of it in half the time.

Comment: Either you're not quoting your homework problem accurately, or your prof is being vague.  If that specification were coming from a nontechnical person, I'd assume that they're asking that the system step response time should be decreased by at least a factor of two -- but in practice, you need to verify how the step response is specified, and whether (and how much) overshoot is acceptable, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *for a plant of second order, can you even measure how fast it reacts?*

Yes, you can measure this accurately and easily. You apply a step change demand and see how long it takes the plant output to settle to the right value within a small tolerance band (maybe 5%).

> *Does someone maybe know what is meant by "react twice as fast"?*

Think of it like this, if you wanted to reach a plant output of (say) \$x\$ you might initially set the plant demand input to \$x\$ in order to establish a baseline time. Then, if you started again but, set the demand to \$2x\$, the plant output would reach the \$x\$ output in a quicker time than the baseline. It would overshoot of course so read-on...

So, if your PI controller modified your \$x\$ demand in such a way so that the plant output was seen to react much faster, you would be partially solving the problem. The final solution would of course require the PI controller to rapidly return its output to \$x\$ when the plant output was close to \$x\$ else you would get massive overshoot in the plant output and it would settle at the wrong value.

It's doable but maybe something more than a simple PI controller. But, that is pure speculation based on no details of the plant provided in the question. Not that I'm offering to solve this problem; there are free tools you can use to design a "speed-up" controller for a "slow" plant.

But the simplest way of thinking about it might be to use a controller that has the inverse response of the plant. OK it sounds easy and theoretically it is but, real-life limitations mean that it's unlikely to work as effectively (and without wrecking your plant) as a bespoke controller solution.

Again, I'll mention modelling and simulation to find a suitable answer.